# Phoenix not loading View module

Tags: session, authentication, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a SessionController with a corresponding SessionView and within the templates directory I have a "session" folder with a "new.html.eex" file. When I navigate to the session_path "new" action I recieve an error:

> HelloWeb.SessionView is not available

It looks like it is calling `SessionView.render/2`

In the session_controller I'm simply trying to render the new.html.eex, here's the new action:

```
def new(conn, _params) do
  render conn, "new.html"
end
```

Phoenix should be rendering the "new" template but the error keeps coming up and I'm not sure why. Everything is spelled correctly and I have the routes correctly mapped in the "router.ex" file.

```
## Routes for sessions ##
get    "/login",  SessionController, :new
post   "/login",  SessionController, :create
delete "/logout", SessionController, :delete
```

However, a call to "login" yields the error

> SessionView.render/2 is undefined (module HelloWeb.SessionView is not available).

What is going on that's causing Phoenix to not load the "new" template?

**Update**: Here is the session_view:

```
defmodule Gofish.SessionView do
  use GofishWeb, :view
end
```

Comment: Can you please show the contents of your session view module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a `session_view.ex` on the `lib/hello_web/views` directory.

Its minimal content will be:

```
defmodule HelloWeb.SessionView do
  use HelloWeb, :view
end
```

Comment: Yes I have a session view with the basic contents. This is why I'm confused as to why it's not working. I have all of the components necessary to render the new.html.eex template but it still throws the error.
    defmodule Gofish.SessionView do
    use GofishWeb, :view
    end

Comment: Frederick, could you put your entire source tree to the Github or somewhere?

Comment: You should change the first line of your `session_view.ex` from `defmodule Gofish.SessionView do` to `defmodule GofishWeb.SessionView do`.

Comment: I was so positive the issue was with phoenix; I can't believe I overlooked that typo so many times and didn't notice it! Thank you!